# Zend 2 - Filter isn't working in my InputFilter class

Tags: zend-framework2

I have the following input filter working with validation but the StringToLower filter just isn't working. Anyone know how this works? The Zend2 documentation doesn't have any examples in the coding method I'm using.

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'cemail',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'string_to_lower',
            ),                
            array(
                'name' => 'StringTrim',
            ),       
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        'isEmpty' => 'Email address is required'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'hostname' => true,
                    'messages' => array(
                        'hostnameInvalid' => 'Invalid email address provided.',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'string_length',
                'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min' => 5,
                    'max' => 150,
                    'messages' => array(
                        'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Email address must not exceed 150 characters',
                        'stringLengthTooShort' => 'Email address must contain at least 5 characters',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Filter directory you will see there's a few there:

```
Zend/Filer/*
```

You should use the filter filename as the name, this will be used when the framework tries to include the Filter class.

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name'     => 'my_field',
        'required' => FALSE,
        'filters'  => array(
            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            array('name' => 'StringToLower'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'StringLength',
                'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'      => 1,
                    'max'      => 45,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )));
```